# Serve a complex object with an image using REST

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Noob WCF/REST question here!
I need to build a simple web service (one method for now), my preference would be for a REST/JSON type of architecture but I'm not sure this can be achieved in my case.

I know that it's easy enough to serialize/deserialize complex objects into/from JSON while using a REST-based service. Even though I haven't tested it yet, it also looks easy enough for a [REST-based service to return an image](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/fetching-image-using-wcf-rest-service/).

However, my scenario may need to serve a mix of both. Below is an example of an object definition that can be returned:

```
class Response
{
  string myTitle;
  string myDate;
  Object myImage; 
}
```

I realize I could store the physical image wherever accessible and then simply return the URL as a string but I would like to avoid the overhead as much as possible.

Is it even possible?

Also note that I'm not committed to REST or JSON in any way, it's simply that all the cool kids are using it so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image as part of the JSON object, convert it into a serializable type. Easiest way is just to use its byte representation.

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("filename");
byte[] imgContent;
using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(m, img.RawFormat);
    imgContent = new byte[m.Length];
    const int count = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i += count)
    {
        m.Read(buffer, i, (m.Length - i < count ? (int)(m.Length - i) : count));
        buffer.CopyTo(imgContent, i);
    }
}
myResponse.myImage = imgContent;
```

**EDIT:** As the OP found, there is a much simpler/quicker way to write:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("filename");
using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(m, img.RawFormat);
    myResponse.myImage = m.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that link answers my question which is how to return a complex object, one attribute of which is an image, the rest being strings. That example is simply about pushing an image back.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if it's possible to return an object that has 3 attributes (2 strings and one image) using REST and JSON. Please see my original question.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try that and report back.

Comment: It didn't quite work as is (index too large for array) so as I was researching a fix, I found something that seems to do the trick and is much leaner. Let me know if you don't think it's appropriate for my usage: `System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("filename");
using (System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    img.Save(m, img.RawFormat);
 myResponse.myImage = m.ToArray();
}`

Comment: @BlazingFrog Good find. I was looking for something to accomplish what `.ToArray` does. I looked for a ReadAllBytes, but didn't find it, so went the longer route.